# Bash grep -E regular expression

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I need help with regex for bash which will match any 1st with last char of a string for example:

```
mam - yes
Pam - no
Mam - yes
Morning - no
AbcdefA - yes
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: In C# it would be `(?i)\b(.).*\1\b`

Comment: The feature you want is called a back-reference. Here is some help: http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Back_002dreferences-and-Subexpressions

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Back_002dreferences-and-Subexpressions.html

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk. First the test file:

```
$ cat file
mam
Pam
Mam
Morning
AbcdefA
```

, then the code:

```
$ awk -F '' '{print $0 " - " (tolower($1)==tolower($NF)?"yes":"no")}' file
```

and the output:

```
mam - yes
Pam - no
Mam - yes
Morning - no
AbcdefA - yes
```